# Python: how to garbage collect strings

Tags: python, string, garbage-collection

I'm having a problem in a large-runtime script. This script is a multithreaded environment, to perform crawling tasks.

In large executions, script's memory consumption become huge, and after profiling memory with guppy hpy, I saw that most of the problem is coming by strings.

I'm not storing so many strings: just get content of htmls into memory, to store them in db. After it, string is not used anymore (the variable containing it is assigned to the next string).

The problem arised because I saw that every new string (with sys.getrefcount) have, at least, 2 references (1 from my var, and 1 internal). It seems that reassigning another value to my var does not remove the internal reference, so the string stills in memory.

What can I do to be sure that strings are garbage collected?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

1- I'm using Django ORM

2- I'm obtaining all of that strings from 2 sources:

2.1- Directly from socket (urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

2.2- Parsing that responses, and extrating new URIs from every html, and feeding system

SOLVED

Finally, I got the key. The script is part of Django environment, and seems that Django's underground is doing some cache or something similar. I turned off debugging, and all started to work as expected (reused indentifiers seems to delete references to old objects, and that objects become collected by gc).

For anyone who uses some kind of framework layer over python, be aware of configuration: seems that some debug configurations with intensive process can lead to memory leaks

Comment: did you try del(my_str_var)?

Comment: if `sys.getrefcount` returns 2, then there is no internal reference, because when you pass the object to `sys.getrefcount`. It will increase the reference count.

Comment: I'm just assigning new strings to old vars. Obviously I trusted pythons's garbage collector, but it seems that it's not enough. Will try to add a "del" in every string call

Comment: `just get content of htmls into memory` <- this is your problem. Update the question with the source of your application (the part that reads the HTML, parses it and then adds to the database) so we can figure out where the _actual_ problem is.

Comment: **just get content of htmls into memory** is not my problem. I get 1 HTML from obj1.var1 = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), then process obj1, then del(obj1); after this step, I process the next one, reasigning to a new object obj2

Comment: I think the same as  Burhan Khalid

Comment: No, you don't REassign if you use another identifier ``obj2`` after ``obj1``. You just assign a new string (= object) to a new identifier. And name ``obj`` for an identifier is deplorable since it is not an object but an identifier. I know, an identifier references an object... but this manner of expressing and writing you have reveals that these notions are nebulous in your mind.

Comment: Without further information, it's impossible to figure out what is the reason of the memory uptake.

Comment: eyquem, is just a VERY SHORT example to show how code is organized. Obviously I'm not using obj as my naming convention...

Comment: By the way, if strings are attributes of instances , it may happen that crossed references exist between data inside an instance and that, even if the identifier of the instance is deleted, these references continue to exist and to keep alive the objects so referenced. If so, it would be necessary to trigger a garbage collection upon the contents of these lasting instances with deleted references.

Comment: I know this is old but using the gc module may help. I use spynner for crawling since I need to parse a ton of resources (urllib2 doesn't do javascript very well and selenium is a hog) and for every term or level call gc.collect() and then on the next line run del gc.garbage[:]. This works for me. If I need to, I can close spynner to get rid of all referents to a string,orphan the entire process, and then collect. A headless browser tool such as spynner or urllib2's opener may be the way to go if the issue persists.

Answer (score 2):

You say:
*I saw that every new string (with sys.getrefcount) have, at least, 2 references*

But did you carefully read the description of `getrefcount()` ? :

> sys.getrefcount()
>
> object)  Return the reference count of the object. The count returned
>   is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the
>   (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().

.

You should explain more about your prohgram.

What is the size of the HTML strings it holds ?
How are they obtained ?  Are you sure to close all file's handler , all socket connexions, ....?

Comment: The size of HTML are arbitrary (some are short, some are huge). I obtain it, store in a object variable, process whole object, and then, delete object. No one exception arised to let objects with references (I tracked that) but I still have more and more strings in system (tracked with guppy heapy) while I'm reusing all my vars

Comment: @user989501 I mean that no available object in Python deserves to be called 'variable'. (There are underlying pointers that are real variables, but they are inaccessible)

Comment: I think that anyone with programming background (in any language) can understand the meaning of "variable" and can understand the translation to python's environment (some identifier that references something in memory). I don't think that my words can mislead someone to think another thing that python's identifiers

Comment: I dislike incorrect wording of things: it spreads a veil of blur on notions, and programming is difficult enough to not add haze of words to haze of mind.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to find out who keeps the "internal" reference to your strings.
Perhaps the library you're using to write to DB (you didn't specify how you write to DB).
I find objgraph very useful for tasks like this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph

E.g.

```
import objgraph
objgraph.show_backrefs([mystring], filename='a.png')
```

Comment: I was using objgraph, but can't get info about strings (it does not track information about objects that call "simple" as ints or strings)